# What is the difference between alert and window.alert?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `alert()` and `window.alert()` functions? It seems to work the same.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Because `window` is the global object, you can call an `alert` either by it's shorthand: `alert( 'Hello!' );` or by referencing the global object specifically: `window.alert( 'Hello!' );`

They are the same.

Comment: it seems that this.alert('Hello!'); does the same job. I guess then that globally we are inside window object.

Comment: what about window.addEventListener ? can we also write addEventListener only ?

Comment: Subject to the same scoping issues mentioned by Eineki below, yes you can.

Answer (score 36):

They are usually the same thing but, if in your scope, see example, the alert function got redefined then alert and window.alert will not be the same function.

```
(function () {
    function alert(test) {
        document.write(test);
    }

    alert("hello page");
   window.alert("hello world");
})()
```

Hope the example will shed more light on this subject than my explanation.

You can also shadow the function name with a variable and obtain an error when calling it.

```
(function () {
    var alert;
    alert("Why don't you work, silly function?");
})()
```