# Why Javascript window.location can't redirect page if condition is true?

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication, window.location

Im just started with javascript and this is for testing.
I have basic login form with username and password, and added some Javascript to pickup username and password values, check them and if its true should redirect me to another html page. 
In this case Im used window.location..

Here is the code

```js
function Validate() {
  username = document.login.korisnicko.value;
  password = document.login.lozinka.value;
  
  if (username == "" || password == "") {
   window.alert ("Ne valja");
   return false;
  }
  else if (password.length < 6) {
   window.alert("mora biti duze od 6 slova");
   return false;
  }
  else {
   window.location = "profil.html";
   return true;
  }
 }
```

```html
<form name = "login">
 <h1 id="greska"></h1>
 <p id="greska2"></p>
 <label>Korisnicko</label> <br>
 <input type ="text" id="korisnicko" name="korisnicko"> <br>
 <label>Lozinka</label> <br>
 <input type ="password" id="lozinka" name="lozinka"> <br>
 
 <button type = "submit" onclick="Validate();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect with values? I recommend to use action attribute and remove else part from the script.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that code will work - what do you see instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uLbycrhm/1/

I wouldn't recommend using `window.location` instead of the proper `location.href`, and I wouldn't recommend using `window.alert` instead of `alert` either ([what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459907/what-is-the-difference-between-alert-and-window-alert)), so I've adjusted that as well. Using `return` here is unnecessary as well, because your function's tied to an `onclick`, not an `onsubmit`.

It's important to know that `location` is kind of an object, here is a link for your reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Answer (score 0):

you can call function with return keyword

```
<script>
function Validate() {
        username = document.login.korisnicko.value;
        password = document.login.lozinka.value;

        if (username == "" || password == "") {
            alert ("Ne valja");
            return false;
        }
        else if (password.length < 6) {
            alert("mora biti duze od 6 slova");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            window.location = "profil.html";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form name = "login" method="REQUEST" action=>
    <h1 id="greska"></h1>
    <p id="greska2"></p>
    <label>Korisnicko</label> <br>
    <input type ="text" id="korisnicko" name="korisnicko"> <br>
    <label>Lozinka</label> <br>
    <input type ="password" id="lozinka" name="lozinka"> <br>

    <button type = "submit" onclick="return Validate();">Submit</button>
</form>
```